# AngularJS code is not working inside MVC partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

Hi have have a web app created with MVC5. I added angular reference to the main layout and `ng-app` with my module to the body of the main layout.

Now in the page(cshtml) I am loading a partial view that is a Wizard. I two simple line of Angular code inside both my page and my partial like this: `{{100/5}}`. The code in the page is working and is displaying 50 but inside the partial view something is happening and what is being showed is the text {{100/5}}

I am loading my partial view at the en of my page using this code:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/DataCollection/_DataCollectionSetup.cshtml", models)
```

Comment: Did you explore generated HTML pages to detect difference?

Comment: Check your browser debugging tools or developer console. Are you seeing any Javascript errors in the error console? Does the generated HTML, in the browser, look as it should? Are all of your files loading correctly?